# List and id in python

Tags: python-3.x, list, memory, memory-address

What is  "[...]" in list ?Why the second output doesn't have double list ?I know that a and b share same id but, Why this is happening?

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b =a
b.append(4)
print(a)

output :[1, 2, 3, 4]


a.append(b)
print(b)

output :[1, 2, 3, 4, [...]]#what happend here ?
```

Answer (score 0):

> Okay i don't know that this is best answer or not Please do correct me
> if i am wrong.

**Try This :**

```
print(b[4][4])  # you can add as many [4] you want and i used [4] because it isthe position of [...] .
```

The output will be same **Output:[1, 2, 3, 4, [...]] **

So i tried getting address of all 'b' as well as 'b[4]' , 'b[4][4]' ......

**using:**

```
print(id(b))
print(id(b[4]))
print(id(b[4][4]))

## All these will return the same address.
```

> So, the list inside list is the same list (a or b) and it continues, this is why you are getting those '...'